# Close popover upon clicking "x"

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a popover which renders a subset of a list of tasks and I'd like it to disappear when I click the button with the class of 'cross'. How can I do this?

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="popovers" data-container="body" data-html="True" data-placement="bottom"
    data-original-title="<?php echo $gp->description.' Omitted Tasks:';?>" 
    data-content="
        <button type='button' class='cross'></button>

        <div class='table-scrollable' style='max-height: 330px; overflow: auto;'>
            <?php foreach($checked as $c): ?>
                <?php if ($c->complete_omit == 2): ?>
                    <span style='font-size:11px'>
                        <?php echo '- '.$c->checklist->description; ?><br>
                    </span>
                <?php endif ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </div>
    ">
    <?php echo $count.' Tasks'; ?>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the popup-market id or class and use the following code.

```
$(".cross").click(function() {
    $('.popup-marker').each(function() {
        $(this).popover('hide');
    });  // this will hide any popup-marker open
});
```

Comment: It is bootstrap, but it's not rending within a modal. I'm after a way to hide a popover rather than a modal.